# JavaScript floating point curiosity

Tags: javascript, floating-point, comparison

I tried doing some floating point comparison and here is what I found:

```
130 === 130.000000000000014210854715 // true
130 === 130.000000000000014210854716 // false
9 === 9.0000000000000008881784197001 // true
9 === 9.0000000000000008881784197002 // false
0.1 === 0.100000000000000012490009027033 // true
0.1 === 0.100000000000000012490009027034 // false
```

I tried running those on Firefox and Chrome with the same results. Okay, I KNOW that floating point comparison is a bad practice and has unexpected behavior. But I just curious about those numbers, why or how does those sequence of fractional digits calculated?

If you wish you could even expand those sequence further (kind of binary searching for the next sequence).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fractional portion exceeds the precision of JavaScript's `Number` type.

JavaScript can only handle the `130.0000000000000` portion of your number, so it becomes `130` (those `0`s have no significance).

Every `Number` in JavaScript is really a 64-bit [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) float, so the number `130.000000000000014210854715` will look like in binary...

```
0,10000000110,10000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Where the groups are sign (`+` or `-`), exponent and significand/mantissa.

You can see that the number `130` is the same...

```
0,10000000110,10000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

You'd need a 128 bit `Number` for JavaScript to be able to tell these two numbers apart, ot use a [*float128* implementation](https://github.com/munrocket/double.js) for JavaScript or [*bignum*](https://github.com/munrocket/double.js).

Comment: then what about 130.000000000000014210854716 in binary?

Comment: @CaptainkurO It has the last bit of the mantissa turned on: `0000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`