# Jquery & C# deciaml and parseflot values are different

Tags: c#, asp.net, floating-point, decimal

I have a backend code and i try to do the same in frontend using jquery.But result's are different.(correct value is C# code retuns value.)

### C# Code

```
var geoConvr = (decimal)141.5 / (decimal(1) + (decimal)131.5); // Result -> 1.0679245283018867924528301887M
```

### Jquery Code

```
var geoConvr = parseFloat(141.5) / (parseFloat(1) + parseFloat(131.5)); // Result -> 0.12505523641184269
```

So i need to get a same value that C# returns from the Jquery code.

Comment: I believe that `decimal` is 128-bit, whereas JavaScript's number system uses a 64-bit float. As to a solution, I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11339506/3181933